# Bubble.io or Weweb which is best for application development

Tags: bubble.io

What's the best Nocode application builder

Bubble.io is very good as a full-stack development platform but is it suitable for the long run? as application becomes more complex as they grow?

Weweb displays that it can be exported as a standalone react application - how feasible is it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of Bubble, because (like you said) it's a full-stack development platform. It has a built-in database, compute layer for backend workflows, and a User system which makes it much faster to build a functional web app.

If all you want is to build the front end and handle the backend with another tool like AWS, then WeWeb may be a good option, as you can't export your app from Bubble.

Answer (score 0):

I use both but more and more I prefer WeWeb.

Bubble's superpower is plugins. You have a plugin for almost everything and can build anything in a couple of clicks, but you'll never own the app. You cannot export anything and you will pay a lot if your app is popular.

As a developer you have all the benefits of reusable elements. You can build a template element and put custom data inside from outside.

Bubble requires a lot of love and patience to build anything because its editor is terrible. Bubble's database isn't really quick. Bubble's API/DB integrations are slow and non-intuituve. If you want to extend the functionality, you need to do hacks and tricks for almost every action, even for custom CSS/JS. You can't really control the visual appearance. It's hard to communicate between frontend and backend workflows. You don't have any loops and can't really process the database records, only one by one.

Bubble is bad at indexing by search engines.

WeWeb gives you all the benefits of visual building, allowing you to modify anything, API integrations are intuitive, you can use any CSS/JS. There are some performance issues, but they have a nice support team.

WeWeb is easier for new users and more advanced for skilled developers. You can choose any backend and database to follow the laws (some countries require to store users data inside the country), you can use the same data/auth from other tools (like FlutterFlow).

If you spend the time on learning WeWeb, you learn a tech stack, not hacks and tricks.

You can always export your project and host it yourself (and if you use SupaBase/SQL/GraphQL, you can also host it).